# Unable to connect to Azure server using FTP

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have developed an app service in Microsoft Azure and am working on it. Now I want to download my source code from the Azure server to my local machine. I have tried using FTP but I am unable to establish a connection.

I don't know what I'm missing from this link: https://medium.com/@michaelhenderson/how-to-download-your-source-code-from-azure-app-service-59c848752b0f.

Can anyone help me out with the issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There could be several reasons for the FTP issue, the exact error message may provide some pointers.

Azure App Service supports connecting via both Active and Passive mode. Passive mode is preferred because your deployment machines are usually behind a firewall.

Kindly check this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp#get-ftp-connection-information

Alternatively, you could copy files directly from Kudu console to local: http://yourwebappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/
(append ‘scm’ to the default WebApps emphasized above)

Navigate to cmd button and you can find your project files under site/wwwroot folder

Also, you could clone the WebApp from Azure App Service to your local Visual Studio (VS) by using VS team explorer.